# Setting an attribute value to a content value with jQuery 3.0

Tags: jquery, html

How do I set an attribute value to content? Something like:

```
<p id="MyParagraph"></p>
```

I want jQuery (3.0) to set the value of `p`'s id to it's content. I know that I may have to nest this p inside another element, like:

```
<div id="divvie">
   <p id="MyParagraph"></p>
</div>
```

So that I can set the selector to something like $("div#divvie p"). Anything?

Thnx in advance.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to set the id equal to your content?

Comment: `<p>test</p>` to `<p id="test">test</p>` Do you want something like this?

Comment: @ravishankar yes I do.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes.

Comment: @ravishankar Here you go, `$("p").attr("id", function(){ return this.textContent; });`

Comment: That will set id of all the `p`

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you need.

```
$("#divvie p").attr("id",this.textContent );
```

**OR:**

```
$("#divvie p").attr("id", $("#divvie p").text() );
```